# How to retain escape sequences while extracting strings from json objects in javascript. (Strings are actually regex patterns)

Tags: javascript, regex, json, web-scraping

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
    var jsonObject = {"regex":"<span class=\"Value\">\\$(.+?)<\\/span>"};
```

My target is to use this regular expression to scrape a value from a html document.

```
    var match = html.match(new RegExp(jsonObject.regex, 'i'));
```

This however returns an error. The problem seems to be that the escape sequences in the regex string are lost in the string jsonObject.regex

A call to jsonObject.regex returns

```
    < span class="Value">\$(.+?)<\ /span>
```

(The escape sequences like \" and \\ are lost)

I could replace the respective characters using javascript, but it seems the inefficient thing to do since I already have the correct format in the json object.

Any clues or workarounds are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong here.

First and foremost, you are trying to build a program that uses arbitrary regular expressions on HTML. *Don't do that.* You have a DOM at your disposal on the client side, you should use one of the selector engines available. Examples include the browser built-in `document.querySelectorAll()`, [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (which is also part of jQuery), [NWMatcher](http://javascript.nwbox.com/NWMatcher/), or an XPath-based selector engine like [XPath.js](http://llamalab.com/js/xpath/).

Then, you obviously do not use a JSON serializer to build your JSON string on the server side, or things like messed-up escaping would not happen on the client side.

Lastly, what you have in your first code sample is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal. JSON is *always* a string:

```
'{"regex":"<span class=\"Value\">\\$(.+?)<\\/span>"}'
```

---

Selecting what you seem to want in jQuery would become as simple as

```
var value = $("span.value").text();
```

But as I said, you are not bound to use jQuery, there are lighter-weight alternatives if HTML-scraping is your main goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helps. I agree that using DOM is a better alternative than scraping using regex since that might often lead to errors. I am actually building over a scraping code which was built using regex. Changing the structure to DOM would require much time